# No sé por qué mi código no corre, alguien me puede ayudar?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>
#include <stdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib>
#include <stdlib>

void ingreso();
void buscar();
void modificaciones();
void salir();
void menu();

char nom[30]; ape[30];
int dpi=0, auxdpi=0, edad=0, tel=0;
bool encontrado=false;

int main(){
   menu();
   return 0;
   system("PAUSE");
}

void menu(){
   int op=0
   do
   {
   cout<<"Registro de Personas";
   cout<<"\n====================";
   cout<<"\n1. Ingreso\n";
   cout<<"2. Busqueda\n";
   cout<<"3. Modificaciones\n";
   cout<<"4. Salir\n";
   cout<<"Ingrese la opcion que desea: "; cin>>op;

   switch(op)
    {
      case 1:
        ingreso();
         break;
      case 2:
        buscar();
         break;
      case 3:
        modificaciones();
         break;
      case 4:
        salir();
         break;
      default:
        cout<<"\nOpcion Incorrecta";
      }
      while(op!=4);
      getch();
      clrscr();

}

void ingreso();
{
    ofstream escritura;
   ifstream consulta;
   bool repetido=false;
    escritura.open("registro.txt", ios::out|ios::app);
   consulta.open("registro.txt", ios::in);
   if(!escritura.fail()&&!consulta.fail())
    {
      cout<<"Ingrese su DPI: "; cin>>auxdpi;
      consulta>>dpi;
      while(!consulta.eof())
        {
         consulta>>nom>>ape>>tel>>edad;
         if(dpi==auxdpi)
            {
            cout<<"\nYa existe un registro con DPI: "<<auxdpi;
            repetido=true;
            break;
            }
         consulta>>dpi;
         }
      if(repetido==false)
        {
         cout<<"\nIngrese su nombre: "; cin>>nom;
         cout<<"\nIngrese su apellido: "; cin>>ape;
         cout<<"\nIngrese su telefono: "; cin>>tel;
         cout<<"\nIngrese su edad: "; cin>>edad;
         escritura<<auxdpi<<" "<<nom<<" "<<ape<<" "<<tel<<" "<<edad<<endl;
         cout<<"\nRegistro agregado"<<endl;
         }
      else
        {
         cout<<"Error, el archivo no se pudo abrir o no fue creado"<<endl;
         }
   escritura.close();
   consulta.close();
    getch();
    clrscr();
    }
}

void busqueda()
{
cout<<"Mantenimiento";
  getch();
    clrscr();
}

void modificaciones()
{
cout<<"Mantenimiento";
 getch();
    clrscr();
}
void salir();
{
    cout<<"Programa Finalizado"<<endl;
                   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Hola José Mata, no puedes dejar simplelemente tu código y espearar a que algiuen lo arregle por tí. Primero intenta hacerlo tú, explica que has tratado de hacer, indiícanos si hay algún mensaje de error y e nque línea aparece, explicacnos que trata de hacer tu código y cual es el comportamiento esperado y que es lo que obtienes en cambio. Y no copies todo el código sino redúcelo a un ejemplo mínimo que reproduzca el problema. Por favor lee: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Es la primera pregunta que formulo, lo siento si lo hice mal. También puedo decir que estaba un poco urgido, pero ya aprendí para la otra, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola José,  mi intención con el comentario es ayudarte a mejorar la pregunta no a criticarte.  Mejórala y ya verás como alguien resuelve tu problema.  Saludos

Comment: José, revisa en la  consola y ahí veras que errores se tienen al analizar tu code. En la respuesta de @AngelAngel puedes ver un análisis que seguramente te será de ayuda..

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde yo entiendo no puedes especificar nada antes del `int main (){}`, ergo tendrías que sacar todos los `void`, `char` e `int` antes del main.

Luego estas volviendo a especificar esas funciones, entonces en tu código ya vas dos veces que especificas lo mismo.

Es como hacer;

```
int main(); int main (){....}; esta incorrecto.
```

También veo que te faltó un `;` que confundiste con una coma en una declaración int.

Pusiste dos veces que incluías la librería `stdlib` cosa que es erróneo, con una basta y sobra para el compilador. Y la sintaxis para incluir X libreria en C++ es; `#include <xxx.h>` (todo junto) cosa que hiciste mal ahí.

Por el `system("pause")` veo que estas programando en `Windows`, yo programo en `Gnu/Linux` con el compilador GCC que no sé si tendrá que ver pero no he visto que uses `printf("");` para mostrar mensajes pero si he visto que usas mucho el `count` para mostrar al usuario algo, te sugiero que revises eso.

Y como te dijo Carlos, no esperes que simplemente poniendo tu código alguien te lo resuelva (yo me puse en generoso y bueno sinceramente).

En C++ tu único límite es tu imaginación ergo podes programar lo que sea.

Comment: No sé a qué se refiere con 'especificar', pero si se refiere a 'definir o declarar variables fuera del main', entonces sí que es posible. Son variables globales...

Comment: Según el estándar C la primera variable en ser declara tiene que ser el int main() sin nungún argumento. No me refiero a que fuera del main no se puede declarar, si no a que int main tiene que ser la primera variable, y estar sin argumentos.

Comment: Falso. `int a = 3; int main() {//Código}` es absolutamente válido a la luz del estándar C99. De la misma forma, el estándar de C más actual (C11) no menciona que esta función main deba o no llevar argumentos, sólo refiere a que si no debe aceptar ningún argumento se debe declarar como `int main(void)`, un `int main()` de acuerdo al estándar implica pasar un número arbitrario de argumentos.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>
#include <stdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib>
#include <stdlib>
```

tiene repetidos algunos include no problem -> "include guards" trabaja para usted, pero lo que realmente tienes que mirar son estos:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

tienes esta linea `char nom[30]; ape[30];` o pones:

```
char nom[30];
char ape[30];
```

o

```
char nom[30], ape[30];
```

El prototipo `buscar` no tiene implemantacion en el codigo y este es llamado desde un `case 2` pero si existe una implementacion para `busqueda()` quizas confundiste `busqueda` con `buscar` a la hora de crearla.

Al `do` le falta `}` en while:

```
}while(op!=4);
```

Hace uso de por ejemplo de esta manera:

```
ios::out
ios::app
cin
cout
endl
```

o les añades `std::` a todos por ejemplo `std::cin` o usas `using namespace std;`

Tienes varias funciones con esta sintaxis:

```
void ingreso();
{
```

Es posible que copiaras el prototipo pero no borraras el `;`

```
void ingreso()
{
```

puede que tengas algunos mas:

si puede evitar el uso de:

```
system("PAUSE");
```

mejor usa la consola para que esta no se cierre, pasandole algun parametro cuando lances la aplicacion, si lo que quieres es ver los resultados o algo
pues esto no es resposabilidad de tu programa el que a ti no te de tiempo a leer algo o similar.

intenta compilar he ir probando el codigo poco a poco si no esta seguro de el, para evitar que todos los errores aparezcan al mismo tiempo.